# Requirejs and backbone app, not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I am learning backbone.js and use require.js to make a modular app.

I've got it working on every browser except IE8 where I get some major errors and a blank, white page.

Here is the [link to the app](http://inutritie.ro/test/), open it in IE8 and see the error.

I have no idea what to do, I have searched and searched and I need help in making it work.

Any ideas?

Here are the errors:

```
SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action 
jquery.min.js, line 4 character 29137
SCRIPT5007: Object expected 
backbone-min.js, line 1 character 17010
```

And here is my main.js file:

```
// file: main.js

    require.config({

        paths: {
            "jquery" : "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min",
            "underscore" : "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min",
            "backbone" : "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.0/backbone-min",
            "text" : "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require-text/2.0.10/text"
        },

        shim: {
            underscore: {
                exports: '_'
            },

            backbone: {
                deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
                exports: "Backbone"
            },

            text : {
                exports : 'text'
            }
        }

    });

    require(['app'], function (App) {

        App.initialize();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using jQuery 2.x, which does not support IE8. Try using jQuery 1.10 instead. Details on [jquery..com](http://jquery.com/download/)